# Sidekiq Two Default Queues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

Both my staging and production apps use the same build command:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -c 2 -q default -q mailers
```

The queue names in my staging application match exactly as the build command states:

[image]

However, my production application displays as such:

[image]

I understand that the prefix for the default comes from my cable.yml:

```yaml
development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV["REDIS_URL"] { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: calendarize_production
```

I don't get why there are two defaults and no mailer queue? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of queues for Sidekiq is not done on `cable.yml` but on `sidekiq.yml`, here is an example:

```yaml
:concurrency: 5
:queues:
  - default
  - mailers

staging:
  :queues:
    - ["my_project_staging_default", 3]
    - ["my_project_staging_mailers", 2]
  :tag: STAGING
  :labels:
    - default
    - mailers

production:
  :queues:
    - ["my_project_production_default", 3]
    - ["my_project_production_mailers", 2]
  :concurrency: 5
  :tag: PRODUCTION
  :labels:
    - default
    - mailers
```

Th risk using `default` without naming it is to share workers between environments. Then I would suggest to name them so you're 100% sure of what's executing where.

Comment: Fair. I only assumed that since there was nothing in my ```sidekiq.yml``` to indicate such prefix. My environments use their own redis and sidekiq processes, so there should be no sharing of workers between those environments. I did as suggested and tested the change on staging. The queue names are still as described above, however my mailing jobs are no longer using the mailers queue and getting stuck in the default queue.

Comment: I finally got it to work as I wanted using [Sidekiq Advanced Options Docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options) and what you provided here. My run command now being ```bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml```